# Mathematica "Show" does not show 2 functions in one graph

Tags: graphics

I found a few of the similar question earlier. Still, somehow Mathematica does not even show the simplest function correctly. There is one that is provided as an example in the Mathematica website:

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3.5}], ListPlot[{1, 4, 9}]]
```

When I even copy the line, mathematica only processes the first function and does not show the points corresponding to `ListPlot` function.
Is there some kind of update I should know of to use `Show`?

At the moment I am using Mathematica 10.0

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I cannot confirm this on 11.0.1, and I've never experienced such behavior in version 10. Maybe try it once more after restarting the kernel...

Comment: On my computer, the points are small blue dots that lie on the plot of x^2. Are you sure they're not visible?

Comment: Try it this way: `Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3.5}], 
 ListPlot[{1, 4, 9}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]]`.  That should make it easier to see the dots.

Comment: Yes got it!
Thanks for the quick replies!